# How can i sure that mysql statements done susseccfully in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I added some field to wordpress commments and add below code for save them :

```
add_action ('comment_post', 'add_comment_bid_values', 1);
function add_comment_bid_values($comment_id) {
    if(isset($_POST['bidprice'])) {
        $bidprice = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['bidprice']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'bidprice', $bidprice, false);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['bidday'])) {
        $bidday = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['bidday']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'bidday', $bidday, false);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['bidprepay'])) {
        $bidprepay = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['bidprepay']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'bidprepay', $bidprepay, false);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['bidsponsor'])) {
        $bidsponsor = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['bidsponsor']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'bidsponsor', $bidsponsor, false);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['bidfetured'])) {
        $bidfetured = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($_POST['bidfetured']);
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'bidfetured', $bidfetured, false);
    }

}
```

Now
How i can sure that comment and it's meta inserted into wordpress database, because some information save by comment_form function and this meta save by above code and also wordpress don't have transaction .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [wp code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/)  says - 'comment_post' action hook is fired immediately AFTER a comment is inserted into the database. That means your code will be executed only if comment successfully inserted in database. For comment meta checking you can do something like that:

```
$result = add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'your_meta_key', $yourMetaValue, false)    
//add_comment_meta will return false on error
if (false === $result) {
    //do something here for example wp_die( __('Comment meta error', 'textdomain') );
}
```